# sudo %wheel: ALL vs. NOPASSWD: ALL - what is the security difference?

Tags: sudo

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

vs.:

```
## Same thing without a password
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**Question**: what additional security does the first example provide vs. the second one?

It gives additional security if **own** user password needed after login in to be root? Why?

Answer (score 5):

The first one,

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

also requires the non-wheel member that is allowed to `sudo -u otheruser` (i.e. to assume the identity of `otheruser`), where `otheruser` *is* a wheel-member, to know the password of `otheruser` before becoming root.

The second one,

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

doesn't require that.

So in a setup where `sudo` is used with the first configuration, not for gaining root access, but for just switching between different user identities (possibly to be able to carry out specific tasks in some situations), a user that is not originally part of the `wheel` group can not gain superuser rights without knowing the personal password of a `wheel` group member whose identity he is allowed to assume.

Comment: you mean NOPASSWD doesn't require password.

Comment: @pepite I got it mixed up when I first wrote it, but it should hopefully be clear now.

Comment: I already wrote in the question: "It gives additional security if own user password needed after login in to be root? Why? " so I know the direct difference between the two, that is not the question.

Comment: @pepite With the first config, if you are not a member of the `wheel` group you need to know two passwords to become `root`: your own (to change into the identity of a user who is in the `wheel` group), and that of the user who is member of the `wheel` group. With the second config, you need only your own password.